# How to determine if method is async at runtime

Tags: winforms, delegates, async-await

I have a legacy project that has hundreds of method signatures for a Winforms event. Obviously the current ones I don't want to go and do BeginInvoke/EndInvoke on because this will cause UI cross threading issues.

However I have need (because of deadlocks) to be able to mark these signatures as async to handle some async commands that we have to be able to do. No other way results in anything other than a deadlock.

I can successfully call the event with BeginInvoke and it works perfectly and asyncs properly etc. However that breaks it out into another thread and breaks the old implementations that we don't want to have to go through and make async and Invoke aware.

So I was investigating using the event.GetInvokationList() and looping through and calling each separately. If the method was async, then begin/end invoke. Otherwise call it straight up on the UI thread.

My only problem is that I can't find any way through reflection to tell if the method signature is async or not.

Anyone know how to figure out if a method is async or not from the MethodInfo or something else from GetInvokationList() values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using .net 4.5, try "AsyncStateMachineAttribute".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

MVarman's answer works for OP, but has a potential risk because `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` can be added manually. To make the check more robust, verify if the state machine is compiler generated.

```
public static bool IsAsync(this MethodInfo m)
{
    var stateMachineAttr = m.GetCustomAttribute<AsyncStateMachineAttribute>();
    if (stateMachineAttr != null)
    {
        var stateMachineType = stateMachineAttr.StateMachineType;
        if (stateMachineType != null)
        {
            return stateMachineType.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For .NET core app, use

```
public static bool IsAsync(this MethodInfo m)
{
    return m?
        .GetCustomAttribute<AsyncStateMachineAttribute>()?
        .StateMachineType?
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>()
        != null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot detect it nor you shouldn't. Methods marked with async are in fact no different than any other synchronous methods. You should invoke them regularly.

Also, Begin/EndInvoke are supposed to solve the problem of marshaling calls to other threads. If you require that particular knowledge i.e. you do not know if the method is supposed to be run on this thread, you should use your own special attributes on such methods rather than the async keyword since they basically are not mixed together.

Comment: Ok, I'll create my own attribute. I would have figured for sure that MS would have added to the MethodInfo class to tell you if the method was marked async or not!

Comment: But it doesn't have to. You also don't know if method uses yield inside, do you? Keyword async is a hint to the compiler, it does not affect the code execution. Hence, you cannot know about it since even if you do, it does not mean a lot to you.

Comment: Note that decompilers still can detect whether or not a method is marked with async.

Comment: If the method is marked as async it runs in another thread no matter how you call it. Hence it's entirely reasonable to want to know if it's going to run in another thread so that you can invoke it properly if calling it from a delegate.

Comment: Asynchronous methods do not run in another thread, they are converted into state machine and each part runs on the calling thread. That is the whole point of async/await, to remove the need from BeginInvoke/EndInvoke.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: They return immediately to their calling function. This obviously doesn't work when you're invoking an event delegate that needs to wait for the result.

Since using .Result and .Wait() hangs the thread in almost all cases these need to be invoked.  Other methods do not and will crash because they're not setup to run in a separate thread and will die. Hence I'm trying to determine if the method is async at runtime based on the delegate information so that I can handle accordingly to support legacy code.

Comment: You need to actually wait? Then schedule a continuation on the Task that is returned with the ContinueWith method(s) instead. But since it is an event handler, I presume that it is a void method in which case you definitely do not know when it is done. Care to take this chat to IM tool or something?

Comment: That would be great! Please PM me at your convenience and we can set something up.

Comment: Color me blind, but I cannot find such option :/